What could cause UI object show differently between game and scene window in Unity?
It happens occasionally, as shown in the screenshot:

The above window is scene window, and the bottom one is game window.

From my experience, the zooming and resolution that is chosen when "simulating" the game in the Game View. I sometimes either needed to correlate the resolution to the Canvas size, either zoom out, either both (depending on scale).

Thank you for sharing this info. Can we say if this happens, the sittuation in scene window is accurate? @TheNomad

The layout mainly ... check your pivot and anchor settings for those elements .. and accurate is whatever ends up in the GameView .. that is what your user will finally see, not the scene view ^^ In doubt make a build and run the app on different resolution devices

Just remember scaling and pivoting play a crucial role on layouts (software-wise: resolutions i.e. 16:9, 21:9, 4:3 etc. and hardware-wise: very wide or curved monitors). But as derHugo said, the best confirmation comes from builds. As for "How can I cover as many setups as possible?", this is where QA comes into play. When asking for alpha and beta testers, while the number of users is important to finding bugs, make sure you cover diverse hardware setups too. So in your case ask for users with different monitors (i.e. extra curved) and ask for testing under as many resolutions as possible.

Thanks to both of you. In my case, as to what I'm testing, the position in "scene window" always is the same with that I calculate manually. And just occasionally the position in "game window" showed differently. But of course as you suggested, testing on real devices is the most accurate.

Keep in mind, setting positions "manually" without taking into account anchors or pivots could cause misalignment on builds as well.

Thanks for the notice, thoses are already considered in the calculation.

Go into your canvas object and set the 'ui scale mode' to Scale With Screen Size and then adjust the reference resolution until it looks right. Hope this helps!
